# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type ** mi proyecto **

Tags: c#, inyeccion-de-dependencias, dotnetcore

estoy creando una web api sencilla de ejemplo pero me sale un error de

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type ** mi proyecto **

en mi clase startup la reseñe con addScope

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IProductosService, ProductosService>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSession();
            //services.AddTransient<IProductosService, ProductosService>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }
```

en mi controller ya le hice todo la coloque en el constructor de la clase de esta forma

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductoIntelectualController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProductosService productosService;

        public ProductoIntelectualController(IProductosService productosService)
        {
            this.productosService = productosService;
        }

----demas codigo
```

en el applicationDbContext tengo llamando la cadena de conexion al json de configuracion

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicactionDbContext"));
            }
        }
```

cuando dejo el AddScope me sale el error:

> Mensaje = Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> xxxxxDomain.IProductosService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> xxxxxx.Domain.ProductosService': Unable to resolve service for type
> 'xxxxx.Datos.Repositories.Interfaces.IProductoRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'xxxxx.Domain.ProductosService'.)   Origen =
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection   Seguimiento de la pila:
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object
> containerBuilder)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
> Ips.DocInv.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType: xxxx.Domain.IProductosService Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType: xxxx.Domain.ProductosService': Unable to
> resolve service for type
> 'xxxx.Datos.Repositories.Interfaces.IProductoRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'xxxx.Domain.ProductosService'.
>
> Excepción interna 2: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve
> service for type
> 'xxxxxx.Datos.Repositories.Interfaces.IProductoRepository' while
> attempting to activate 'xxxxx.Domain.ProductosService'.

si lo quito y o lo coloco en comentario (services.AddScoped<IProductosService, ProductosService>();) sale el error mencionado inicialmente.

No se que estoy omitiendo ya he realizado todas las instrucciones de [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Answer (score 2):

La documentación que estás mostrando hace referencia a la inyección de dependencias con un DBContext, para lo cual te recomiendo mejor seguir esta [otra página de la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) que incluye información acorde a tu escenario.

Dicho lo anterior, para evitar este error me parece que solo faltaría que tu clase `ProductoService` herede de `IProductoService`, por tal motivo no se puede realizar la activación. Siguiendo estos simples pasos podrás solucionar el problema:

Interfaz:

```
public interface IProductosService
{
     //Definición
}
```

Clase:

```
public class ProductosService : IProductosService
{
     //Implementación
}
```

En el Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<IProductosService, ProductosService>();
    ...
}
```

En tu controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductoIntelectualController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProductosService _productosService;

    public ProductoIntelectualController(IProductosService productosService)
    {
        _productosService = productosService;
    }
}
```

---

Como extra, si deseas conocer un poco más la diferencia entre `AddScoped`, `AddTransient` y `AddSingleton`:

`AddTransient` son siempre diferentes y una nueva instancia es creada para cada controller y cada servicio.

`AddScoped` se reutiliza el mismo objeto para el mismo request pero se crea una instancia diferente para multiples requests

`AddSingleton` el objeto se reutiliza para cada request y cada servicio.

Comment: la clase product service esta heredando así:  

 public class ProductosService : BaseService<ProductoIntelectual>, IProductosService
    {
        private readonly IProductoRepository _productoRepository;

Answer (score 0):

el constructor de ProductosService tiene una variable extra que tienes que pasar

`public MyService(string dependencyString) { //... }`

`services.AddScoped<IMyService>(_ => new MyService("value here"));`